# Concatenate unicode character (warning sign) with string in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, unicode

I have a unicode character for warning sign- Unicode Character “⚠” (U+26A0)
https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+26A0

I am trying to append this to a string variable but i am not successful in appending the image
Can anyone let me know how to append it here, Also i am trying to make the warning sign yellow in color.

for e.g.
I want the result as -> ⚠ Warning Sign

I tried the following but didnt succeed

```
let result = `U+26A0` + 'Warning Sign'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `String.fromCharCode(num1)` method.

Edit:

That is, `String.fromCharCode(0x26A0) + " Warning Sign"`

Comment: Wow. i didnt know this exist. It worked for me.

Comment: one minor question before accept this. is there a way to color the warning sign to yellow ?
i tried String.fromCharCode(0x26A0).fontcolor('yellow') but it says fontcolor is deprecated

Comment: any suggestion for above comment pls

Comment: `String.fromCharCode(0x26A0) + " Warning Sign"` only takes care of the content of the string. To change a character's color, you'll need to use HTML/CSS. Exactly how depends on the context. You can probably wrap ⚠ with `<span style="color: yellow;">` and `</span>`.

Answer (score 0):

You just use "\u{26A0}" as a regular string